# How to remove null and 0 from the map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to remove **NULL** from the map for a long time.....

```
      sortedMap.removeWhere((key, value) => value == "NULL");
    sortedMap.removeWhere((key, value) => value == NULL);
```

...however, this could not be done, and I decide to set the default value "**No Data**", this solved the problem.

```
sortedMap.removeWhere((key, value) => value == "No Data");
```

and, this solved the problem! Now, I can’t remove the value "0" from the map now.

```
 sortedMap.removeWhere((key, value) => value == "0");
sortedMap.removeWhere((key, value) => value == 0);
```

This's my map:

```
{h_1: 0, h_2: 1, h_3: 1, h_4: 1, h_5: 0, h_6: 1}
```

Please, tell me.
How to solve this problem?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your code should works, can you provide more information on your map?

Comment: Dart uses `null`, not `NULL`. It is also strongly typed, meaning `"0" != 0` and `"null" != null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! the code was correct, the problem was, this is still an assumption, that it was necessary to carry out a complete reboot.  thnx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it same solution like yours?
In my case, it works well.

[image]

```
void main() {
  Map data = {'h_1': 0, 'h_2': 1, 'h_3': 1, 'h_4': 1, 'h_5': 0, 'h_6': 1};
  
  print(data);
  data.removeWhere((k, v) => v == 0);
  print(data);
}
```

Comment: exactly! i wrote same lines  `map.removeWhere((key, value) => value == 0);` 
however, this didn't work, there were objects with values of 0 in the logs after a ride to delete these objects
however, now all the objects are deleted .. to be honest, I'm in shock ...) Perhaps, it would be necessary to do not a "hot" reload but a complete reload....., anyway....thank you very much for responding=)

Answer (score 0):

What is **NULL**? Is it perhaps **null** you are looking for to remove?

(**Null** in the case below is a class from dart:core)

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
void main() {
  test(
    'Remove null',
    () {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c': null,
        'd': 4,
      };
      print(map);
      map.removeWhere((key, value) => value == Null);
      print(map);
      map.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
      print(map);
      // assert
    },
  );
}
```

This prints:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: null, d: 4}
{a: 1, b: 2, c: null, d: 4}
{a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}
✓ Remove null
```

Comment: I fetched this from the server, `{time_21: 2020-10-22 03:28:16, time_10: NULL, time_1: 2020-11-11 11:28:16, time_2:  NULL, time_15: NULL}`  The values were not removed when I wrote the commands until then. until you assign a value to the default "No Data"=>   `map.removeWhere ((key, value) => value == "No Data")`  The problem with removing the null value has been partially solved, unfortunately. I still do not understand. what was causing this error=/